# ssh to a remote terminal and bypassing dotrc files

Tags: ssh, remote-access, tcsh

I want to rapidly execute a remote command using `ssh`, for example `ls -al /path/to/myfile`.   Unfortunately, I'm using `tcsh` rather than `bash`.
My `.cshrc` file is quite long and slow, so I'd like to bypass it.
If I were using `bash`, I could (presumably) run

```
ssh simon@192.168.7.179 "bash --noprofile --norc" < lsFile
```

where `lsFile` contained the `ls` command.    But `tcsh` doesn't support either of these flags.      Is there an alternative way to accomplish the same effect within the `tcsh` shell?

If not, an alternative would be to condition on something at the top of my `.cshrc` file and exit it prematurely.    I can't simply condition on whether I have an `ssh` connection, because for most of my ssh connections, I want to run the full `.cshrc` file.    So I'd need to send the conditioning token within this particular ssh command.   Is this possible?

Comment: Which version and distro of Linux are you using?

Comment: `man tcsh` suggests the equivalent option is `-f` (*The  shell  does  not  load any resource or startup files, or perform any command hashing, and thus starts faster.*)

Comment: @user68186, I'm running ubuntu, 20.04.    Here's the output of `uname -a`   `Linux 7420 5.13.0-1010-oem #11-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 28 13:04:29 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`          Thanks @steeldriver, I don't know how I missed that.      The command took 5 seconds instead of 7, which is something of an improvement!